# How can I add a persistent detent to a SwiftUI view without obscuring the bottomBar?

Tags: swiftui

Is there a way to always show a presentation detent along with an always visible bottom toolbar in SwiftUI. Currently the detent obscures the bottomBar.

I’d also like to make sure I can interact with the main view the sheet view and BottomBar simultaneously.

I have SwiftUI View with the following toolbar

```
  `   .toolbar {
        ToolbarItemGroup(placement: .bottomBar) {
            Button("First") {
                print("Pressed")
            }

            Button("Second") {
                print("Pressed")
            }
        }
    }`
```